# Pod not init and install

Tags: cocoapods, xcode9.3

I have create fresh project and when i am going to pod init , the error throw me by Terminal in the below screen shoot. Please help me any one know about the issues.

Racs-iMac-2:DemoApp nirajpaul$ pod init
[in /Users/nirajpaul/Desktop/Aquarios/DemoApp/Latest_Code]

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

`/usr/local/bin/pod init`

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 1.3.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [universal.x86_64-darwin17]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2
        Host : Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
       Xcode : 9.3 (9E145)
         Git : git version 2.15.0
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ f5323f3d52f6cd25258153d89864257f6cb86a37`

#### Plugins

`cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.1
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0`

#### Podfile

```ruby

## Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project

## platform :ios, '9.0'

use_frameworks!

target 'DemoApp' do

pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

end
```

#### Error

`` RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:217:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.4/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:102:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.3.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>' ``

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5BXcodeproj%5D+Unknown+object+version.&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
 - Unknown object version
   https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7760 [closed] [1 comment]
   a week ago

- RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version.
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7697 [closed] [17 comments]
  3 days ago
- RuntimeError - [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version. 
  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7712 [closed] [9 comments]
  3 weeks ago

and 38 more at:
https://github.com/cocoapods/cocoapods/search?q=[Xcodeproj]%20Unknown%20object%20version.&type=Issues&utf8=✓

Comment: You should provide us with the entire error stack trace.

Comment: @AndreaGottardo. I have past all the issues stack

Comment: See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7458. Try running `gem install cocoapods` to update CocoaPods.

Comment: Also, a Google search for `[Xcodeproj] Unknown object version` will return a number of related results.

Answer (score 5):

Sometime the latest project format may not support immediately, try to check your Project Format:

1. Click the Project in the Project Navigation
2. Check the Project Format under Project Document

[image]